# Loop conflict in Perl

Tags: perl, loops, while-loop

I have a script with two loops:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Bio::Graphics;
use Bio::SeqFeature::Generic;

$seq = "";
$seqlength = length($seq);
$count = 0;
while ($line = <>) {
  if (/^>/) {
    $count = 1;
    next; }
  if ($count == 1) {
    chomp;
    $seq .= $line; }
 }

while (<>) {
  chomp;
  next if /^\#/;
  my @gff_data = split /\t+/;
  next if ($gff_data[2] ne "gene");
  my $feature = Bio::SeqFeature::Generic->new(
                                              -display_name => $gff_data[8],
                                              -score        => $gff_data[5],
                                              -start        => $gff_data[3],
                                              -end          => $gff_data[4]
                                             );
  $track->add_feature($feature);
}
```

Without the first loop, the second loop works. However, with the first loop, the second loop does not work. Why is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each `while` will exhaust reading the file passed to the script, so omitting one lets the other do its job.

Comment: how can I avoid this? Using two loops and not joining loops.

Comment: @user2886545 - Are you just processing fasta files?

Comment: It's a GFF file.... but after ##FASTA in some line, the following one it's a header (>jkdssd) and then the sequence, like a fasta file.

Comment: @user2886545 - Have you considered using a dedicated module like [Bio::Tools::GFF](http://search.cpan.org/~cjfields/BioPerl-1.6.901/Bio/Tools/GFF.pm)?

Comment: You don't need to read through the file twice. The first loop builds a big string. The second loop could act upon that string instead of re-reading what is already in memory.

Answer (score 0):

In each of the while loop you are using <>, which is by default resembles take the input from `STDIN` i.e `<>` is equivalent to `<STDIN>` and `while (<>)` is equivalent to `while($_ = <>)` or to be more specific `while ($_ = <STDIN>)`
So at any point of time you cannot run both the while loops. Since both the while is an infinite loop. If you want both the loop to work instead of using STDIN use a file handle, created via `open` command and use the same filehandle  , assuming FH is the filehandle variable, then store all the lines in

```
@lines = <FH>
```

and then use these @lines in your while loop.